# getStaticProps runs on every request

Tags: next.js, getstaticprops

when I saw the doccumentation of Nextjs I found out that the difference between `getServerSideProps` and `getStaticProps` is that the first runs on every request while the second runs in the background and when using `revalidate`.

but here I have this code inside my `getStaticPros`

```
export async function getStaticProps() { 
console.log("this is my getStaticProps"); 
const response = axios.get("/words/get-all"); 
return { 
    props: { 
     words: response.data, 
    }; 
} 
}
```

but every time I navigate to `/words` page I see ""this is my getStaticProps" in the console. what I am missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when I saw the doccumentation of Nextjs

this is also mentioned in the [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-props#runs-on-every-request-in-development) of Nextjs

> **Runs on every request in development** :
> In development (next dev), getStaticProps will be called on every request.